# Java Spark Data Encoding

Tags: java, apache-spark, encoding

Is there a way to set the encoding in SparkConf? I'm building a Java application with Spark that processes Arabic data. When I run it in the dev environment with Spark Master set to Local[*], data is processed correctly. However, when I prepare the JAR and submit it to Spark Cluster, data seems to need encoding.
I used:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

as configuration in Spark submit, but didn't work.
OS: Windows 10
Java 1.8.0.131
Spark 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading textual data, Spark uses the underlying Hadoop InputFormat, which assumes UTF-8 encoding. If your data is actually UTF-8, then it should be read correctly. If not, you will need to convert it before passing it to Spark.

Handling other character encodings has been raised an an issue ([SPARK-1849](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1849)) but has been marked as "Won't Fix".

It is odd that your data works in a local job, but not a cluster job - but you may need to provide further details before anyone here can help - e.g. what OS are you using for the cluster and for your client node - and how do you know there is an encoding problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my question with the environment details.